# Changing world's in flashpunk

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make my first  **actual** game in AS3, for this I am using flashpunk due to it's simplicity.

I have got to the point where I have a moving character and a textbox when I go infront of a door.

When I am infront of a door, two variables are changed inside the player class:

```
public var onDoor:Boolean = false;
public var doorType:String = ""
```

You can probably guess what onDoor does, doorType is the name the class. It's set like this:

```
    public static var BedroomDoor:Door = new Door(350, 331, "ApartmentBedroom")
```

ApartmenBedroom being the name of the world the door leads to.

Inside the main class where flashpunk is initialised, I have this function:

```
    public static function ChangeLevel(world:String)
    { 
        var newWorld = getDefinitionByName(world) as Class
        FP.world = new newWorld
    }
```

But when I go to the door and press X infront of the door which calls the function, I always get this error:

[Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ApartmentBedroom is not defined.

Can anyone help fix this?

Comment: Whenever use `getDefinitionByName(classname)`, the classname should contain the full package path.
`getDefinitionByName("com.your.domain.ApartmentBedroom")`

Comment: so like this? getDefinitionByName("com.Worlds.ApartmentBedroom"). I'm still getting the same error. Worlds is the package ApartmentBedroom is in.

Comment: AS3 syntax disallow upper case first letter in package name.

Comment: same thing.    getDefinitionByName("com.worlds.ApartmentBedroom")

Comment: 1.Is the package name correct? /
2.Is this no errors? `new ApartmentBedroom();`

Comment: Yes and yes. But just hard coding it to always go to ApartmentBedroom defeats what I want to do which is have a door which leads to a room. I need to be able to access the first map (ApartmentLivingroom) from the bedroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `getDefinitionByName()` you have to include your class in the code first. Anything will do, for example simple `var a:ApartmentBedroom;` or more complex one like `var allLevelsClasses:Array = [ApartmentBedroom, ApartmentLivingRoom];`

So your Main.as code should look like this:

```
public static function ChangeLevel(world:String)
{ 
    var allLevelsClasses:Array = [ApartmentBedroom, ApartmentLivingRoom]; // put everything here

    var newWorld = getDefinitionByName(world) as Class
    FP.world = new newWorld
}
```

Also you could avoid full classname confusion when creating Door. Instead of passing string with its name into Door constructor just pass world's class:

```
private var worldClassName:String;

public function Door(x:Number, y:Number, worldClass:Class):void
{
    /// init what's necessary
    this.worldClassName = getQualifiedClassName(worldClass);
}
```

And later just:

```
public static var BedroomDoor:Door = new Door(350, 331, ApartmentBedroom)
```